# Is regex the best way to extract data from log

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've got a file full of log and I'm trying to extract some data from those log, a log look like:

```
IP_adress - - [Date_time] "method" response_nb time "page" "UA" "IP_adress"
```

I want to extract the IP_adress and UA.
Is using a regex a good idea to extract data from those log or is there some other way to do it properly?

Comment: Try logstash, You have to write grok pattern which may have predefined patterns to support your requirement.

Comment: What is your criteria for "the best way"? Without that information, you're just asking for our opinion. If you're asking if it's possible to do with regex, yes, it certainly is, it just may be a little more difficult to get just right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the string and get last two elements.

```
>>>
>>> str = 'IP_adress - - [Date_time] "method" response_nb time "page" "UA" "IP_a
dress"'
>>> tmp_list = str.split()
>>>
>>> tmp_list
['IP_adress', '-', '-', '[Date_time]', '"method"', 'response_nb', 'time', '"page
"', '"UA"', '"IP_adress"']
>>> tmp_list[-1]
'"IP_adress"'
>>> tmp_list[-2]
'"UA"'
>>>
```

If first IP Adress is required...

```
>>> tmp_list[0]
'IP_adress'
>>>
```

Replace double quotes as below from last IP Adress.

```
>>>
>>> tmp_list[-1].replace('"','')
'IP_adress'
>>>
```